# Why telethon does not work with tor bundle

Tags: python-3.x, tor, telethon

my OS Windows 10. i did setup local proxy socks5 with tor bundle. I'm using python 3.8.1 and telethon 1.10.10. But my code don't work

```
import socks
import logging
from telethon import TelegramClient, connection

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
api_id = 123
api_hash = '123'
client = TelegramClient('123', api_id, api_hash,
                                              proxy=(socks.SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', 9050))

client.start()
```

Telegram service connection log

```
C:\source\untitled2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/source/untitled2/tele.py
DEBUG:asyncio:Using proactor: IocpProactor
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connecting to 149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull...
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 1...
WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Attempt 1 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 2...
WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Attempt 2 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 3...
WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Attempt 3 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 4...
WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Attempt 4 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 5...
WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Attempt 5 at connecting failed: TimeoutError: 
DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 6...
WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Attempt 6 at connecting failed: TimeoutError:
```

Comment: Are you sure the proxy is properly configured (is it `SOCKS5`, in that IP, in that port)?

Comment: @Lonami yes, my telegram desktop is currently working with these settings

Comment: @Lonami I just installed Linux and this code works in Linux, maybe this will help you to improve the code